# Does TTimer.OnTimer causes a worker thread to synchronize with a main thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, timer, delphi-2009

I have to work with legacy code. This code has a `TTimer` created in a main thread.
In `OnTimer` event the timer is checking periodically a state of some data in the worker thread.

pseudocode:

```
procedure MainForm.OnTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if WorkerThread.Data.State = full then
  begin
    WorkerThread.Free; //This freezes GUI.    
  end else
   //Do something else.
end;
```

The problem is that I want to do some background operation when the `WorkerThread` is terminating. To avoid synchronization I've overriden `DoTerminate` method. However in this particular case, this is not helping and my GUI becomes frozen until the `DoTerminate` finishes.

Can I somehow avoid the freeze?

Thanks.

Comment: So what are you doing in DoTerminate?

Comment: Some database stuff. I am not synchronizing with GUI.

Comment: Not enough code here. Calling Free on a thread calls Terminate and then WaitFor. Would that explain the freeze?

Comment: More code. The thread execute method would be good. You can replace any confidential stuff with 'SOME SQL', 'open database connection' or the like in the post so we can see what's happening without violating any NDA/whatever.

Comment: Your code explicitly freezes GUI thread until WorkerThread is terminated. What else you could expect?

Comment: @David Thanks, your suggestion was correct. Care to make it as answer, so I could close the topic? Sorry for not providing more code but it would be very tedious task to build a proper example to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not enough code here to say anything with any certainty. However, calling `Free` on a thread results in a call to `Terminate` followed by a `WaitFor`. It's quite plausible that the wait is not returning which would be consistent with the frozen UI.

Answer (score 0):

This is truly backwards. In any decent threading scheme, your thread will be notifying your gui-thread about a condition like .Data.State = full. You gui-thread or main-thread will then take appropriate action. One thing i am certain about is that WorkerThread.Free must be wrong. Trying to free a thread that's apparently blocked for whatever reason, is guaranteed to fail. Thread.Terminate will also fail if the thread is blocked, so no help there either.

Having a Timer monitor the status of a thread is never right. I never use the words always and never, but... I'll repeat: Having a Timer monitor the status of a thread is never right. Never ever. Don't even think about it.

- turin

Comment: I disagree, at least in part. For checking status a timer is a good low priority means, and allows the thread to get on with the business no matter what the main thread is doing. But I do agree that this is a poor use here as is is not just showing status but actively controlling too.

Comment: @Turin I agree that it is almost never right. But as I wrote earlier it is a legacy code and the timer was there from the begining.